# Authentification failed ssh2_auth_pubkey_file()

Tags: php, ssh, remote-access, libssh2

I try to write a PHP script that would connect to a remote server by ssh and executes a command. 
this is my code so far:

```
 $ssh = ssh2_connect($ip,22);
 $boolean = ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($ssh, $user, './pubkey.pub', './privatekey.ppk');
 $stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, $command);
 stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
```

My Script returns following exception:

```
 Warning: ssh2_auth_pubkey_file() [function.ssh2-auth-pubkey-file]: Authentication failed for $user using public key in file.php
```

When i connect with Putty and my private key i can connect without any issue.

I generated the public key out of my .ppk file with PuttyGen.

Could anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think you'd be better off using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('privatekey'));
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Among other things it doesn't require a separate public key and private key file. So that's one potential problem for you. A mismatch in public / private key files.

Also, with phpseclib, you could enable logging and see where, exactly, it was failing, whereas libssh2 offers no such feature.